# Inequality $\log x\le \frac{2}{e} \, \sqrt{x}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, radicals

The inequality $$\log x \le \frac{2}{e} \, \sqrt{x},$$ where $\log x$ denotes the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm), is used in the [proof of Theorem 4.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=fSP4CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA85) in Apostol's Analytic Number Theory.

It seems that the inequality is not very difficult to prove using calculus. We could simply find maximum/minimum of some function like $f(x)= \frac2e \sqrt{x} - \log x$ or $g(x)=\frac{\log x}{\sqrt x}$.

Are there some other methods how this inequality can be proved? Is there a way in which this inequality can be seen more directly, without having to calculate critical points of some auxiliary function?

Comment: With $\log$ you mean $\ln$?

Comment: @Stef rouquin ?

Comment: @Stef Yes, as I said in the post, $\log x$ is the natural logarithm. (I kept the notation of the book from which I took the inequality.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok, thanks. So, I will not change to $\ln$.

Comment: The inequality roughly amounts to "the value of an integer exceeds the number of its digits".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you elaborate? (That sounds interesting, but why does that lead to the square root in the LHS?)

Comment: @ClementC.: you can ignore the square root by setting $x=t^2$. This question belongs to the family $\log(x)\leftrightarrow ax+b$.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the substitution $x = e^{2(u+1)}$ the inequality
$$
\log x \le \frac{2}{e} \, \sqrt{x}
$$ becomes
$$
   e^u \ge 1 + u \tag{*}
$$
which is a well-known estimate for the exponential function.
Equality holds if and only if $u = 0$, corresponding to
$x = e^2$ in the original inequality.

$(*)$ is trivial for $u \le -1$ and can for example be shown using
the Taylor series for $u > -1$. It also follows – as Jack said in a comment –
from the convexity of the exponential function: the graph lies above
the tangent line at $u = 0$.

(This approach was inspired by [Jack D'Aurizio's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1578523/42969).)

Comment: Also from $(1+u/n)^n=1+u+\cdots$.

Comment: It is just a consequence of convexity. Very nice, +1.

Answer (score 3):

With a change of variable, $x=e^{2t}$, the given inequality is equivalent to:
$$ t e^{-t} \leq \frac{1}{e}. \tag{1}$$
Let we set $f(t)=t e^{-t}$. We have $f'(t)=(t-1)e^{-t}$, hence $t=1$ is the only stationary point of $f(t)$. Quite trivially, it is an absolute maximum, hence:
$$ f(t) \leq f(1) = \frac{1}{e} \tag{2}$$
follows.

Comment: Modulo the change of variable, isn't this the very same as the proof "with calculus" the OP describes ?

Comment: @user10000100_u: I agree it is almost the same proof, but that change of variable make things a lot easier to grasp, at least to me.

Comment: That's personal perception, but do you agree that your answer is not really an answer to "Are there some other methods how this inequality can be proved? Is there a way in which this inequality can be seen more directly, without having to calculate critical points of some auxiliary function?" ;-)

Comment: @user10000100_u: Yes, I agree with that point of view. Anyway, through the non-answer of mine someone (Martin R) has found a great real answer. So I am proud enough anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Letting $x=(eu)^2$, the inequality is equivalent to

$$\log u\le u-1$$